# How to get previous 7 dates from a particular date in java?I am getting 7 dates from present date, but I want from particular date

Tags: java, android, date, android-date, java-calendar

```
//explain
public class DateLoop {
    static String finalDate; 
    static String particularDate;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d-M-yyyy ");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        particularDate = "2-1-2018";
        // get starting date
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -7);

        // loop adding one day in each iteration
        for(int i = 0; i< 7; i++){
            cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
            finalDate =sdf.format(cal.getTime());
            System.out.println(finalDate);
            //ie, its giving previous 7 dates from present date, but I want
            //particular date... thanks in advance
        }
    }

}
```

ie, its giving previous 7 dates from present date, but I want previous 7 dates from particular date.

Comment: Having a variable `particularDate` does nothing to the calendar instance. You have to actually set it to that date.

Comment: In java 8 u can use LocalDateTime to achieve that easily.Read about it please.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 )
         .minusDays( … )
```

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

Use `LocalDate` for a date-only without time-of-day.

Using the `Month` enum.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;  // 2018-01-23.
```

Using month numbers, 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 2018 , 1 , 23 ) ;  // 2018-01-23.
```

Collect a sequence of dates.

```
List<LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<>( 7 ) ;
for( int i = 1 ; i <= 7 ; i ++ ) {
    LocalDate ld = start.minusDays( i ) ;  // Determine previous date.
    dates.add( ld ) ;  // Add that date object to the list. 
}
```

For earlier Android, use the *ThreeTen-Backport* and *ThreeTenABP* projects.

Answer (score 1):

As Uta Alexandru and Basil Bourque have said already, don’t use the long outmoted classes `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API also known as JSR-310, is so much nicer to work with:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-M-uuuu");
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2-1-2018", dtf)
            .minusDays(7);

    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        date = date.plusDays(1);
        String finalDate = date.format(dtf);
        System.out.println(finalDate);
    }
```

This prints:

```
27-12-2017
28-12-2017
29-12-2017
30-12-2017
31-12-2017
1-1-2018
2-1-2018
```

Not only is the code slightly simpler and shorter, more importantly, it is clearer and more natural to read.

### Question: Can I use `java.time` on Android?

You certainly can. It just requires at least Java **6**.

- In Java 8 and later the new API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310).
- **On Android**, use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where the modern date and time API was first described.

Comment: I am getting exception running in android studio:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/format/DateTimeFormatter;

Comment: You’re on the right track. Change your import statements to import `org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter` and `org.threeten.bp.LocalDate` (the classes from the backport instead of those from the `java.time` package).

Comment: can you please tell me the dependencies to import org.threeten.bp?

Comment: You need [the ThreeTenABP project](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), it’s all explained here: [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project). Sorry, I don’t know more than it says there. @SATYAJITTARAFDAR

Comment: Oh!! "SEXY" thanks a lot, I got from the sample project and its working perfectly.

Comment: dependencies is: compile group: 'org.threeten', name: 'threetenbp', version: '1.3.3', classifier: 'no-tzdb'

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have some date from some data do something like below.

```
public void dateFromRandomDate(String date){
    SimpleDateFormat formatter2=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");  
    Date date2=formatter2.parse(date); 
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    //this sets the date to given date
    calendar.calendar.setTime(date2);
    //now call getTime() or add ,subtract date from here
    //this will add 1 year to given one,similarlly others will work.
    calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR,1);
}
```