# How to convert a Gregorian date to an Islamic (Hijri) date?

Tags: android, calendar

I know this question was asked many times but I didn't find the correct way. I have a `String` date like 01-08-1994. And I want to convert it to a `Hijri` date.
using `IslamicCalendar`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intellij - Unable to use newer Java 8 classes - Error : "Usage of API documented as @since 1.6+.."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787079/intellij-unable-to-use-newer-java-8-classes-error-usage-of-api-documented)

Comment: No . I edited my question .

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to read the documentation of `IslamicCalendar ` but I couldn't able to know exactly how to convert my `Gregorian` date to `Hijri` . So please delete your comment which say my qustion is dublicated and I see it isn't .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution here in this [new library](https://github.com/msarhan/ummalqura-calendar)  .

Answer (score 5):

## java.time

```
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu");
String gregorianString = "01-08-1994";
LocalDate gregorianDate = LocalDate.parse(gregorianString, dateFormatter);
HijrahDate islamicDate = HijrahDate.from(gregorianDate);
System.out.println("Islamic date: " + islamicDate);
```

This prints:

> Islamic date: Hijrah-umalqura AH 1415-02-23

I assumed your string meant 1 August 1994. If January 8 was intended instead, swap `dd` and `MM` in the format pattern string in the code.

## ThreeTenABP

To use the above on Android below API level 26 you will need to add the [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) library to your project first.

I haven’t got the experience, but I have been told that the dependencies are: `compile group: 'org.threeten', name: 'threetenbp', version: '1.3.3', classifier: 'no-tzdb'`. See the links below for more details. I have tested the code above with the backport, only not the Android edition of it.

## Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.
- [Comment about dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48174580/how-to-get-previous-7-dates-from-a-particular-date-in-javai-am-getting-7-dates/48176266#comment83349252_48176266) for ThreeTenABP