# Does FTPClilent commons-net:3.9.0 not supported on Android 7 and below?

Tags: android, kotlin, ftp, ftp-client

I am using Apache Commons Net to download files through `FTPClient`. There is no problem when using version `3.8.0.`

But after upgrading to `3.9.0` the app crashing on instantiating the `FTPClient` with the below stacktrace:

```
 E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mozyn.android.example, PID: 14556
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/Duration;
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.<init>(FTPClient.java:544)
        at com.mozyn.android.example.services.DownloadService$startMyDownloadService$1$1$1$downloadResult$1.invokeSuspend(DownloadService.kt:188)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@aa100d1, Dispatchers.Main]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.time.Duration" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mozyn.android.example-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mozyn.android.example-1/lib/x86_64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        ... 10 more
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.time.Duration
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 11 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

The `DownloadService.kt:188` points to the constructor onf FTPClient(), while `FTPClient.java:544` points to `private Duration controlKeepAliveTimeout = Duration.ZERO;`.

Also noticed that the constructor of the `FTPClient` in 3.9.0 version uses java.time API [which is supported in API 26+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57144294/9851608).

Dependency used:

```
implementation("commons-net:commons-net:3.9.0")
```

Is there anyway to upgrade to 3.9.0 version or just stuck with the 3.8.0 version for supporting Android 7 and below?

Thanks!

Comment: Dont let your app crash by catching that exeption.

Comment: Updated from 3.4 to 3.9.0 and it went wrong for Android 6 and 7 although with different exception.

Comment: @blackapps thanks but catching the exception still crashing with the same exception.