# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/format/DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, android, android-studio, localtime

Getting a crash of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/format/DateTimeFormatter] older android versions especially like Android Version 7.0 and 7.1. Basically i am calling to api with the help of retrofit 2 and also using the object of `LocalTime`. Below is the java code and log

> MainActivity.Java

```
public class PrayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Dialog dialog;
    TextView fajrTv,dhuhrTv,asrTv,maghribTv,ishaTv,dateTv,locationTv;
    Button btnMethod,btnSearch;
    AutoCompleteTextView search;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_prayer);
        btnMethod = findViewById(R.id.btnMethod);
        btnSearch=findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        fajrTv=findViewById(R.id.fajrTv);
        dhuhrTv=findViewById(R.id.dhuhrTv);
        asrTv=findViewById(R.id.asrTv);
        maghribTv=findViewById(R.id.maghribTv);
        ishaTv=findViewById(R.id.ishaTv);
        dateTv=findViewById(R.id.dateTv);
        locationTv=findViewById(R.id.locationTv);
        search=findViewById(R.id.search);
        linearLayout=findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        dialog=new Dialog(this);
        String[] cities=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cities);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(PrayerActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,cities);
        search.setAdapter(adapter);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        btnMethod.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openMethod();
            }
        });
        btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SearchAPI();
            }
        });
        search.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                keyboard();
                search.setCursorVisible(true);
                String selectedData=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                ArrayAPI(selectedData);
            }
        });
        linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                hideSoftKeyboard(PrayerActivity.this);
            }
        });
    }
    private void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =
                (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(
                        Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(PrayerActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        Animatoo.animateSlideRight(PrayerActivity.this);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(PrayerActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            Animatoo.animateSlideRight(PrayerActivity.this);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    private void ArrayAPI(String passData) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("METHOD", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences1=getSharedPreferences("SCHOOL", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int method = sharedPreferences.getInt("key",4);
        int school = sharedPreferences1.getInt("keyS",0);
        keyboard();
        if (passData.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(PrayerActivity.this,"Please enter city name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(PrayerActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.show();
            Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(APIInterface.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            APIInterface apiInterface=retrofit.create(APIInterface.class);
            Call<Prayer> call=apiInterface.getPrayer(passData,method,school);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<Prayer>() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Prayer> call, Response<Prayer> response) {
                    Prayer prayer=response.body();
                    String fajrMain=prayer.getData().getTimings().getFajr();
                    String dhuhrMain=prayer.getData().getTimings().getDhuhr();
                    String asrMain=prayer.getData().getTimings().getAsr();
                    String maghribMain=prayer.getData().getTimings().getMaghrib();
                    String ishaMain=prayer.getData().getTimings().getIsha();
                    String dateMain=prayer.getData().getDate().getReadable();
                    double locationMainLat=prayer.getData().getMeta().getLatitude();
                    double locationMainLong=prayer.getData().getMeta().getLongitude();
                    LocalTime localTimeFajr = LocalTime.parse(fajrMain, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm")); //In this line it is getting crashed
                    String fajrResult=localTimeFajr.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a"));
                    LocalTime localTimeDhuhr = LocalTime.parse(dhuhrMain, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
                    String dhuhrResult=localTimeDhuhr.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a"));
                    LocalTime localTimeAsr = LocalTime.parse(asrMain, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
                    String asrResult=localTimeAsr.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a"));
                    LocalTime localTimeMaghrib = LocalTime.parse(maghribMain, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
                    String maghribResult=localTimeMaghrib.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a"));
                    LocalTime localTimeIsha = LocalTime.parse(ishaMain, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
                    String ishaResult=localTimeIsha.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a"));
                    fajrTv.setText(fajrResult);
                    dhuhrTv.setText(dhuhrResult);
                    asrTv.setText(asrResult);
                    maghribTv.setText(maghribResult);
                    ishaTv.setText(ishaResult);
                    String city = "";
                    String country="";
                    Geocoder geocoder;
                    List<Address> addresses;
                    geocoder = new Geocoder(PrayerActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
                    try {
                        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(locationMainLat, locationMainLong, 1);
                        city=addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                        country=addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    dateTv.setText(dateMain);
                    locationTv.setText(city+", "+country);

                    pDialog.hide();
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Prayer> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
    private void SearchAPI() {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("METHOD", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences1=getSharedPreferences("SCHOOL", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String mLocation=search.getText().toString().trim();
        int method = sharedPreferences.getInt("key",4);
        int school = sharedPreferences1.getInt("keyS",0);
        keyboard();
        if (mLocation.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(PrayerActivity.this,"Please enter city name",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            final ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(PrayerActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            pDialog.show();
            Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(APIInterface.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
            APIInterface apiInterface=retrofit.create(APIInterface.class);
            Call<Prayer> call=apiInterface.getPrayer(mLocation,method,school);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<Prayer>() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Prayer> call, Response<Prayer> response) {
                    Prayer prayer=response.body();
                    String fajrMain=prayer.getData().getTimings().getFajr();
                    String dhuhrMain=prayer.getData().getTimings().getDhuhr();
                    String asrMain=prayer.getData().getTimings().getAsr();
                    String maghribMain=prayer.getData().getTimings().getMaghrib();
                    String ishaMain=prayer.getData().getTimings().getIsha();
                    String dateMain=prayer.getData().getDate().getReadable();
                    double locationMainLat=prayer.getData().getMeta().getLatitude();
                    double locationMainLong=prayer.getData().getMeta().getLongitude();
                    LocalTime localTimeFajr = LocalTime.parse(fajrMain, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
                    String fajrResult=localTimeFajr.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a"));
                    LocalTime localTimeDhuhr = LocalTime.parse(dhuhrMain, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
                    String dhuhrResult=localTimeDhuhr.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a"));
                    LocalTime localTimeAsr = LocalTime.parse(asrMain, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
                    String asrResult=localTimeAsr.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a"));
                    LocalTime localTimeMaghrib = LocalTime.parse(maghribMain, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
                    String maghribResult=localTimeMaghrib.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a"));
                    LocalTime localTimeIsha = LocalTime.parse(ishaMain, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm"));
                    String ishaResult=localTimeIsha.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a"));
                    fajrTv.setText(fajrResult);
                    dhuhrTv.setText(dhuhrResult);
                    asrTv.setText(asrResult);
                    maghribTv.setText(maghribResult);
                    ishaTv.setText(ishaResult);
                    String city = "";
                    String country="";
                    Geocoder geocoder;
                    List<Address> addresses;
                    geocoder = new Geocoder(PrayerActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
                    try {
                        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(locationMainLat, locationMainLong, 1);
                        city=addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                        country=addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    dateTv.setText(dateMain);
                    locationTv.setText(city+", "+country);

                    pDialog.hide();
                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<Prayer> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

> LOGCAT

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nabil.myapplication, PID: 1675
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/format/DateTimeFormatter;
        at com.nabil.myapplication.PrayerActivity$5.onResponse(PrayerActivity.java:164)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:71)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
```

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52510370/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-ljava-time-localdate-erro?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash yes, i have checked but same error i am getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/LocalDate;`