# Check Hour Android and do something Java

Tags: java, android, date, time

Good morning, i would want to know how to do something like this in android.

```
if(6PM are already passed){
 //do somethin
}else{
//somethin else
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Get current time ```Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();``` and check as per your requirement

Comment: how can i now make i check                                                                                                             Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

        if (currentTime.before())

Comment: `if (LocalTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()).isAfter(LocalTime.of(18, 0)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function, you can extend it with dates if you want after:

```
public static void checkTimings() {
    String pattern = "HH:mm";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);

    try {
        Date date1 = sdf.parse(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        Date date2 = sdf.parse("18:00");
        if (date1.before(date2)){
            //before 6pm
        } else {
            //after 6pm
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider not using the old and troublesome classes `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Calendar`. Use java.time, it is so much nicer to work with. See the answer by Chaosfire. And if for API levels under 26 additionally use core library desugaring to make java.time available to you.

Comment: no problem, If you want to check date, you need just to change the pattern and get current date

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

1. **Modern `java.time` API**

```
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("required timezone"));
if (now.getHour() >= 18) {
    //do something
} else {
    //do something else
}
```

2. **Legacy [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)**

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Rome"));
int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

Keep in mind, using the legacy API is cumbersome, error prone and generally discouraged, it's just that bad. I would recommend to research how to do [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table).

Comment: thanks for the reply but it give me this error                                              Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/ZoneId;                                                                                    My timezone is   LocalTime now = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Rome"));

Comment: @AlbertoDev2 Probably your API version is too low, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52510370/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-ljava-time-localdate-erro) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55550936/call-requires-api-level-26-current-min-is-23-java-time-instantnow).

Comment: yeah i know. but i need it to API 23 because my phone has android 6 is there another way to do it for lower API versions..?

Comment: You can use `java.time` on lower API version through [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table).

Comment: do you have an example?

Comment: @AlbertoDev2 I can't help with that, sorry. I don't do android stuff, so my knowledge about desugaring is to the extent - i know it exists. Check the update how to get hour using the legacy API, but keep in mind, it's just bad, it's better to do research on desugaring, android docs should have examples.

Answer (score 1):

To use `java.time` in low Android versions easily, you can use

**1.** [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP)

Put this in your `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.4.1'
```

Then in your Application class:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  AndroidThreeTen.init(this);
}
```

That's all, now use `java.time` normally.

**2.** Or, as their github README suggests, use the new [desugaring library](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring)

Answer (score 0):

if other solutions didn't work for you. You can try this

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
if(currentTime.getHours() >= 18){
     // Above 6pm
} else {
     // Below 6pm
}
```

Comment: Thank you I solved my problem using mokhtar halim code.